# mysqldump: Got error: 1356: using MySQL Workbench/command line

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Am Getting below error message when i try to export using the MySQL Workbench or the command line form the server.

**Error Message from MySQLWorkbench:**

10:36:07 Nothing to do, no schemas or tables selected.

10:36:12 Dumping TEST (all tables)
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\15\tmphs85jqd6.cnf"  --host=192.168.40.31 --port=3351 --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --protocol=tcp --column-statistics=FALSE --force=TRUE --skip-triggers "TEST"
mysqldump: Got error: 1356: View 'TEST.schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `schema_table_statistics`': View 'TEST.schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `schema_table_statistics_with_buffer`': View 'TEST.schema_table_statistics_with_buffer' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)
mysqldump: Got error: 1356: View 'TEST.schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them when using LOCK TABLES

Operation failed with exitcode 2
10:36:14 Export of b'D:\Test\DatabaseBackup\202111011013-FileName.sql' has finished with 1 errors

**Error Message from Command Line:**

$mysqldump -u root --password='Password' --all-databases > /bkp/202111011013-FileName.sql

mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1356: View 'TEST.schema_table_statistics' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them when using LOCK TABLES

Comment: These (schema_table_statistics, schema_table_statistics_with_buffer) objects are created under tables which is causing the issue to fail the database export both on the MySQL WorkBench & command line. Dropping these two views will cause any issue on the Database side?

Comment: These views are in the sys schema, which you should not export in the first place. You cannot drop views from the sys schema.

Comment: @Shadow this is not available in the SYS schema, this was created in the our APPLICATION database (TEST). Can we drop it?

Comment: If these views are in your application database, then only you can tell if you can drop them, we cannot.